# Accessing custom font from Jar

Tags: java

I am going to use custom font in my application. For that I am using `Font.createFont()` method.
My code is given below. It works fine when I run my main class using command

> java myAppl.class

The font file is in same directory that of my class file. But when I bundled all files and font files in JAR and then run my application from JAR, the custom font do not loaded. Why?

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("myfont.TTF");
uniFont=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,is);
Font f = uniFont.deriveFont(24f);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is the path to the font correct and it is not something like resources/fonts/myfont.TTF in the jar file? Also make sure the case is correct.

Answer (score 4):

1. Make sure the case of the font file name & extension is exactly the same in code as on the file system.  Windows may not be case sensitive, but Java is.
2. Check the `InputStream` returned by `getResourceAsStream()` for `null`.  If it is `null`, that indicates the resources was not located.
3. Put the font in the root of the Jar and add "/" as the prefix to the name.

Answer (score 1):

As Andrew response, I've tested exactly code above and works:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/myfont.TTF");
uniFont=Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,is);
```

Just missing "/" before file name. Note: jar package by Netbeans

Answer (score 0):

Try copying the font to the jre/lib/font folder

or use the package-qualified name ("com.mypackagename.myfont.TTF")