# jFreeChart : Displaying correctly unicode characters in a chart

Tags: unicode, jfreechart

I'm creating a chart with `jFreeChart` :

```
final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
            "Line Chart Demo 1",       // chart title
            "Caf\00E9",                    // domain axis label
            "Voil\00E0",                   // range axis label
            dataset,                   // data
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,  // orientation
            true,                      // include legend
            true,                      // tooltips
            false                      // urls
        );
```

As you can see, I have unicode characters for the labels in the axis :
"Caf\00E9" to display "Café" and "Voil\00E0" for "Voilà".

It works well when the app that generates this chart runs on "some" servers. For the others, it displays question marks ("?") instead of accentued chars.

As it doens't run all the time, I had the idea to force the encoding.

The question is : How can I force the labels to convert those unicode characters into readable ones ? 
I cannot find in the documentation a way to can convert those strings properly.
I found some pieces of code on the net like this

```
domainAxis.setTickLabelFont(new Font("Lucida Sans Unicode", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

which I find interesting but, how could I apply it to the domain axis and range axis labels ?

Regards.

**EDIT1:**

I figured out how to "force" using a font :

```
Font font = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12);
categoryplot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(font);
```

But, the output is still odd : for "Caf\00E9", it shows "CafÃ©". Is there a way to transform this string into a readable one (Café) ?

Comment: I'm guessing that "some" servers have more/better fonts than others. You might run `xlsfonts` on one of each and `diff` the results.

Answer (score 1):

(I'd rather like to comment, but this reputation limit still blocks me ...)

It might be just a copy&paste typo, but please check that your [unicodes are starting with "\u"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585919/creating-unicode-character-from-its-number).

Furthermore on "some" (*nix) servers you might want to [load the font from your own resources.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669477/accessing-custom-font-from-jar)