# How to load Fonts from a jar?

Tags: java, fonts, jar, jframe, embedded-resource

I am using java.awt.Frame for my Java application window which is being refreshed from a loop inside main.

The application behaves exactly as it should when it is run from Eclipse, but when I package it into a jar, It draws the first screen, but then nothing else after that.

when I try switching the window to a JFrame, it works, but only a portion of the images get drawn and updated.

I'm not sure what the problem is? If it runs fine from eclipse, shouldn't it run the exact same in a jar file?

EDIT: I figured out the problem. Its due to fonts not loading from the jar file. Is there a way to get these to load correctly? This is my code for them:

```
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, 
  obj.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fontName));
```

Comment: Tell us what the `fontName` variable contains, where the file of the font is in your jar, and what `obj.getClass()` returns.

Comment: This question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5669477/130224

Comment: I already tried what he said, and fontName is a string that holds "/Fonts/custom.ttf"

Comment: I also meant to put a .ToURI() in the post but thats not the problem

Comment: Start by removing the leading slash from the font name, and if it still doesn't work, answer the rest of my questions.

Comment: So, how about answering the rest of my questions? It's the third time I ask you to answer these questions. Do you really want to be helped?

Comment: I did if you loom at the other comments. I said that fontName holds "/Fonts/custom.ttf". The font is literally in /Fonts in the jar. i tried removing the slash and that didn't work. And obj.getClass is a method in the object class, the base class of every object in java

Comment: It's the first time you say where the file is in the jar. And I have 120K reputation, so don't you think I know what `obj.getClass()` does, and that Object is the base class of every object. I'm asking you what it *returns*, i.e. what the value of `obj.getClass()` is, i.e. what the class of the object referenced by the variable `obj` is.

Comment: I honestly could care less what your reputation is. there is absolutely no reason to be condescending. I already figured out what the problem was. So for anyone who has this problem in the future, you have to use getResourceAsStream() rather than getResource

Answer (score 1):

Get an URL to it, then see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364787/how-do-you-import-a-font/8365030#8365030) for creating it and registering it amongst the available fonts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for loading font files from within a .jar file.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class FontLoader
{
    private ResourceLoader loader;

    public FontLoader(String fontFilePath)
    {
        loader = new ResourceLoader(fontFilePath);
    }

    public Font getFont(int fontStyle, float fontSize) throws FontFormatException, IOException, URISyntaxException
    {
        Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, loader.getResource());

        font = font.deriveFont(fontStyle, fontSize);

        return font;
    }
}
```

Note that you also need my `ResourceLoader` class which you can find here:
[How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder/28283998#28283998)