# How do I load a file from resource folder?

Tags: java, file, maven

My project has the following structure:

```
/src/main/java/
/src/main/resources/
/src/test/java/
/src/test/resources/
```

I have a file in `/src/test/resources/test.csv` and I want to load the file from a unit test in `/src/test/java/MyTest.java`

I have this code which didn't work. It complains "No such file or directory".

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(test.csv))
```

I also tried this

```
InputStream is = (InputStream) MyTest.class.getResourcesAsStream(test.csv))
```

This also doesn't work. It returns `null`. I am using Maven to build my project.

Comment: Doesn't work how?  What is your error?

Comment: try this `this.getClass().getResource("/test.csv")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891375/how-to-read-a-text-file-resource-into-java-unit-test

Comment: @SRy it worked (cause this will give absolute path url in return ) however the moment i make jar file it's not working as its inside a jar and absolute path becomes invalid, is there a way to play with relative path itself

Comment: @SRy, somewhere between now and 2013, this seems to have been fixed. I am today able to load root resources without the initial `/`. However, I do `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename)`... maybe that's the difference?

Answer (score 360, accepted):

Try the next:

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = classloader.getResourceAsStream("test.csv");
```

---

If the above doesn't work, various projects have been added the following class: [**`ClassLoaderUtil`**](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java)<sup>1</sup> (code [here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java/?v=source)).<sup>2</sup>

Here are some examples of how that class is used:

```
src\main\java\com\company\test\YourCallingClass.java
src\main\java\com\opensymphony\xwork2\util\ClassLoaderUtil.java
src\main\resources\test.csv
```

```
// java.net.URL
URL url = ClassLoaderUtil.getResource("test.csv", YourCallingClass.class);
Path path = Paths.get(url.toURI());
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

```
// java.io.InputStream
InputStream inputStream = ClassLoaderUtil.getResourceAsStream("test.csv", YourCallingClass.class);
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    // Process line
}
```

---

*Notes*

1. [See it](https://web.archive.org/web/20171212030426/http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.opensymphony/xwork/2.1.3/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java) in *The Wayback Machine*.
2. Also in [GitHub](https://github.com/krosenvold/struts2/blob/master/xwork-core/src/main/java/com/opensymphony/xwork2/util/ClassLoaderUtil.java).

Comment: thx for the answer, could you please explain why we should use this very specific loader but not that of the class ?

Comment: great, I'm so stupid that I was using `Object.class.getClassLoader();`, from a static context which didn't work - this suggestion does - well almost, it injects `%20` for spaces which gives me a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: @ycomp Because getResource returns a URL, not a file.  The getFile method of java.net.URL **does not** convert a URL to a file;  it just returns the path and query portions of the URL.  You shouldn't even try to convert it to a File;  just call openStream and read from that.

Comment: Check this project, solves resources folder scanning: https://github.com/fraballi/resources-folder-scanner

Comment: to convert to string in one line: `new String(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my_file_in_resources.bzip").readAllBytes())`

Comment: The one liner suggested by @prayagupa only works in Java 9 or higher, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54269211/cant-resolve-method-readallbytes

Answer (score 123):

Try:

```
InputStream is = MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.csv");
```

IIRC `getResourceAsStream()` by default is relative to the class's package.

**As @Terran noted, don't forget to add the `/` at the starting of the filename**

Comment: For those seeking sanity, this post brings you all the way to getting the resource as a `String` https://stackoverflow.com/a/35446009/544045

Comment: The "/" is the key.

Answer (score 71):

Try following codes on Spring project

```
ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("fileName");
InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

Or on non spring project

```
 ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
 File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("fileName").getFile());
 InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Comment: Should the InputStream not be closed?

Comment: This answer works on a war file not for a jar file.

Answer (score 44):

Here is one quick solution with the use of [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava):

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Resources;

public String readResource(final String fileName, Charset charset) throws IOException {
        return Resources.toString(Resources.getResource(fileName), charset);
}
```

Usage:

```
String fixture = this.readResource("filename.txt", Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: The docs say that this about the `getResource` method: `'getResource(java.lang.String)' is declared in unstable class 'com.google.common.io.Resources' marked with @Beta`. Should people really be using methods from an unstable class?

Comment: what is `this` in your usage example? why people cannot attach the whole code needed?

Answer (score 21):

Non spring project:

```
String filePath = Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("any.json")).getPath();

Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath));
```

Or

```
String filePath = Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("any.json")).getPath();

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

For spring projects, you can also use one line code to get any file under resources folder:

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.CLASSPATH_URL_PREFIX + "any.json");

String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
```

Answer (score 14):

For java **after 1.7**

```
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(getClass().getResource("test.csv").toURI()));
```

Alternatively you can use Spring utils if you are in Spring echosystem

```
final val file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:json/abcd.json");
```

To get to more behind the scene, check out following blog

https://todzhang.com/blogs/tech/en/save_resources_to_files

Comment: I must use "/test.csv" (note the slash).

Answer (score 7):

I faced [the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27703508/read-file-from-src-main-resources).

The file was not found by a class loader, which means it was not packed into the artifact (jar). You need to **build the project**. For example, with maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

So the files you added to resources folder will get into maven build and become available to the application.

I would like to keep my answer: it does not explain how to read a file (other answers do explain that), it answers **why** `InputStream` or `resource` was **null**. Similar [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55409569/4587961).

Comment: Thanks, saved me from thinking I was losing my mind!

Answer (score 5):

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream("test.csv");
```

If you use context ClassLoader to find a resource then definitely it will cost application performance.

Comment: Programmers should always be concerned about performance.  While premature optimization is certainly to be avoided, knowing the more efficient approach to take is always good.  It's like knowing the difference between LinkedList and ArrayList and when to use one or the other.

Comment: @Marvo: Programmers must always be concerned about quality, capabilities and ease of maintenance, performance is at the queue.

Answer (score 5):

Now I am illustrating the source code for reading a font from maven created resources directory,

> scr/main/resources/calibril.ttf

[image]

```
Font getCalibriLightFont(int fontSize){
    Font font = null;
    try{
        URL fontURL = OneMethod.class.getResource("/calibril.ttf");
        InputStream fontStream = fontURL.openStream();
        font = new Font(Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, fontStream).getFamily(), Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        fontStream.close();
    }catch(IOException | FontFormatException ief){
        font = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
        ief.printStackTrace();
    }   
    return font;
}
```

It worked for me and hope that the entire source code will also help you, Enjoy!

Comment: Can you tell us the full name of `Font` class?

Answer (score 3):

Import the following:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

The following method returns a file in an ArrayList of Strings:

```
public ArrayList<String> loadFile(String filename){

  ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

  try{

    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classloader.getResourceAsStream(filename);
    InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
    for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
      lines.add(line);
    }

  }catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe){
    // process errors
  }catch(IOException ioe){
    // process errors
  }
  return lines;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the com.google.common.io.Resources.getResource to read the url of file and then get the file content using java.nio.file.Files to read the content of file.

```
URL urlPath = Resources.getResource("src/main/resource");
List<String> multilineContent= Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(urlPath.toURI()));
```

Answer (score 1):

getResource() was working fine with the resources files placed in `src/main/resources` only. To get a file which is at the path other than `src/main/resources` say `src/test/java` you need to create it exlicitly.

the following example may help you

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        URL location = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location.getPath().toString().replace("/target/classes/", "/src/test/java/youfilename.txt")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("filename").getPath()
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are loading file in static method then
`ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();`
this might give you an error.

You can try this
e.g. file you want to load from resources is resources >> Images >> Test.gif

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("Images/Test.gif");

File file = resource.getFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

To read the files from  src/resources folder then try this :

```
DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(getFileHandle("images/sample.jpeg"));

public static File getFileHandle(String fileName){
       return new File(YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
}
```

in case of non static reference:

```
return new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

Answer (score 1):

For Kotlin I am doing the following:

1. I created an assets folder in my project
   (for Android studio go to File -> New-> Folder -> Assets Folder)
2. Copied my assets (.txt files) to this folder
3. Then I used the code below

Import these items:

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.util.Log
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

I created a function like this:

```
    fun loadBook(context: Context) {
       val assetManager = context.assets
       try {
          val inputStream = assetManager?.open("19-Psalms.usfm")
          val lineList = mutableListOf<String>()

          inputStream?.bufferedReader()?.forEachLine { lineList.add(it) }
          lineList.forEach{println(">  $it")}
      }
      catch (e:FileNotFoundException) {
          Log.e("FileNotFoundException","File not found")
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the code work when not running the Maven-build jar, for example when running from your IDE? If so, make sure the file is actually included in the jar. The resources folder should be included in the pom file, in `<build><resources>`.

Comment: When using eclipse and running code from IDE itself. How can we load resources located at "/src/test/resources" in Java code specifically in unit tests. Consider a standard maven project structure.

Answer (score 0):

The following class can be used to load a `resource` from the `classpath` and also receive a fitting error message in case there's a problem with the given `filePath`.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;

public class ResourceLoader
{
    private String filePath;

    public ResourceLoader(String filePath)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;

        if(filePath.startsWith("/"))
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Relative paths may not have a leading slash!");
        }
    }

    public InputStream getResource() throws NoSuchFileException
    {
        ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();

        InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(filePath);

        if(inputStream == null)
        {
            throw new NoSuchFileException("Resource file not found. Note that the current directory is the source folder!");
        }

        return inputStream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work on both running jar and in IDE by writing as

```
InputStream schemaStream = 
      ProductUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(jsonSchemaPath);
byte[] buffer = new byte[schemaStream.available()];
schemaStream.read(buffer);

File tempFile = File.createTempFile("com/package/schema/testSchema", "json");
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
out.write(buffer);
```

Comment: How does your file structure look like?

Answer (score 0):

My file in the test folder could not be found even though I followed the answers. It got resolved by **rebuilding the project**. It seems IntelliJ did not recognize the new file automatically. Pretty nasty to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing it this way.

This is my structure.
[image]

```
final String path =   "src/test/resources/archivos/B-163.txt";
final Path filePath = Path.of( path );
final String documento = Files.readString( filePath );
         
log.debug("DOCUMENTO: {}" , document);
```

I am working with Java 11.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin:

```kotlin
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths

val lines = Files.readAllLines(
    Paths.get((object {}).javaClass.getResource("videos.txt").toURI()),
    StandardCharsets.UTF_8
)

lines // will contain list of lines in a file
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked pretty fine for me :

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/xxx.xxx");
InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
String content = "";
for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
    content += line;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I get it to work without any reference to "class" or "ClassLoader".

Let's say we have three scenarios with the location of the file 'example.file' and your working directory (where your app executes) is home/mydocuments/program/projects/myapp:

a)A sub folder descendant to the working directory: 
myapp/res/files/example.file

b)A sub folder not descendant to the working directory: 
projects/files/example.file

b2)Another sub folder not descendant to the working directory: 
program/files/example.file

c)A root folder: 
home/mydocuments/files/example.file (Linux; in Windows replace home/ with C:)

1) Get the right path:
a)`String path = "res/files/example.file";`
b)`String path = "../projects/files/example.file"`
b2)`String path = "../../program/files/example.file"`
c)`String path = "/home/mydocuments/files/example.file"`

Basically, if it is a root folder, start the path name with a leading slash.
If it is a sub folder, no slash must be before the path name. If the sub folder is not descendant to the working directory you have to cd to it using "../". This tells the system to go up one folder.

2) Create a File object by passing the right path:

```
File file = new File(path);
```

3) You are now good to go:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```