# How can I read my file which is in a resources folder in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, path

I have created a new folder in "scr" with the name "resources". There I have put my file "Test.txt". Now I would like to read in this file with a BufferedReader. This is my current code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("/resources/Test.txt").getFile());
in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

But it doesn't work! The file is not found. Why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a file from resource folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Comment: Text file needs to be in a 'resources' folder, which needs to be in a folder with a directory path matching the package of the class. If the fully-qualified class is a.b.c.D, then the file needs to be in a/b/c/resources

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the resources folder to your [Build Path](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-properties-build-path.htm), and change

```
classLoader.getResource("/resources/Test.txt").getFile()
```

to

```
classLoader.getResource("Test.txt").getFile()
```