# How to target resource file on spring project?

Tags: java, spring

Maybe this is dupe. If so, sorry. I can't find the answer.

I want to add image on excel spreadsheet for my spring project.
(Spring boot 1.4.2 + JExcelAPI)

Where I have to put the image file?
And how can I target that file?
Not work as below.

```
new WritableImage(0, 0, 1, 1, 
  new File(getClass().getResource("/src/main/resource/image.png"))
);
```

Comment: It's better to use the file bytes (as far as I can see WritableImage does not have a constructor with InputStrema). As it was suggested by @EssexBoy the path should be `\image.png`. But access getClass().getResourceAsStream("\image.png") and get the bytes from the stream. Then just use the bytes in constructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a file from resource folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Answer (score 2):

If you use [apache commons](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.5)

You can do this:

```
new WritableImage(0, 0, 1, 1, IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/image.png")));
```