# How do I get the relative path?

Tags: java

My project structure is

Project--src--com--java--service--serviceImpl.java

Project--src--resources--patientDetails.sql

How do I access patientDetails.sql file inside the sericeImpl.java class.

Please let me know the relative path

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("??/patientDetails.sql"))
```

Comment: `src/resources/patientDetails.sql` does not work ?

Comment: is it a maven or gradle project?

Comment: Please check the link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder

Comment: It is a maven project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InputStream stream = <Current_Class>.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.csv");`

This method returns an input stream for reading the resource, or null if the resource could not be found.