# How to get resources folder(files) from other maven module?

Tags: java, maven, module

I have some amount of child maven modules in parent module.
How can I get access from one module to resources of another and to have this solution stable in jar file ?
I tried something like: (resource.txt - is situated in first module, and code is executing in second)

```
String pathToFirstModuleResource = ClassFromFirstModule.class.getClassLoader().getResource(resource.txt).getFile();
```

But it points me to `...firstmodule/target/classes/resource.txt`, so it works almost good, but returns not a resource folder, but `target/classes`. Why it returns this targets folder, though should to return `...firstmodule/resources/resource.txt`?

Comment: see this post may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder/46452118#46452118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why it returns this targets folder, though should to return ...firstmodule/resources/resource.txt?

No.
It looks like you configured `resources` being threaded by your IDE as a *souce folder*.
Therefore the folder `resources` only exist in your *development environment*. At runtime the file is simply copied to the root of your jar, which merely is the content of `target/classes`.