# Spring boot project can't find the static file

Tags: spring-boot, static, controller, file-exists

Recently, I meet a problem when I try to write content in the static file, [image: here is my project structure.]

When I enter the "localhost:8080/data/user.json", I can get the file. However, when I tried to write content in the index html, FileNotFound error occurs.
My controller is:

```
    @Controller
    public class UserController {

        UserService userService = new UserServiceImpl();

        @RequestMapping("/")
        public String getIndex(){
        return "/index.html";
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      @ResponseBody
      public Response<Boolean> register(String user, String password)throws         IOException{
         System.out.println("Get Register");
         System.out.println("user" + "  " + user);
         System.out.println("password" + " " + password);

        return userService.saveUser(user, password);
    }

}
```

FileTool class:

```
     public class FileTool {

    public static boolean writeFile(String filePath, String content) throws IOException{
        try {
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(writer);
            printWriter.write(content);
            System.out.println(content);
            printWriter.println();
            writer.close();
            printWriter.close();
            return true;
        }catch (IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

How should I write the true path in the my tool in util.
I write the path "data/user.json", the error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: data/user.json (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
at com.utag.phase1.util.FileTool.writeFile(FileTool.java:12)
at com.utag.phase1.dao.UserDaoImpl.saveUser(UserDaoImpl.java:20)
at com.utag.phase1.service.Impl.UserServiceImpl.saveUser(UserServiceImpl.java:19)
at com.utag.phase1.controller.UserController.register(UserController.java:41)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:881)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
   <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="login"/>
   <input type="button" id="btn2" value="register"/>
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
           $("#btn").click(function () {
              var user = $('#username').val();
              var password = $('#password').val();
              $.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:"/login",
                dataType:"json",
                data : {
                user: user,
                password: password
            },

            success : function (data) {
                if(data.success){
                   alert("Success!");
                }else
                    alert("Error!");
            },
            error : function () {
                alert("Network warning");
            }
        });
    });

        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            var user = $('#username').val();
            var password = $('#password').val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/register",
                dataType:"json",
                data : {
                    user: user,
                    password: password
                },
                success : function (data) {
                    if(data.success){
                        alert("Success!");
                    }else
                        alert("Error!");
                },
                error : function () {
                    alert("Network warning");
                }
            });
        });
}
);
```

Comment: post the errors

Comment: Thanks, I posted it.

Comment: What you wrote in `index.html`?

Comment: That's the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read data from resources, here the correct code

```
    //Get file from resources folder
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    File file = new File(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile());
```

Or you can refer to this link

[How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Comment: Sorry, but I also need to write, the path seems right... Could you please give me some advice?

Comment: The homework requirement is that we can't use database, so the json file is the data (write and read) , orz.

Comment: What should have in json file ?

Comment: As the user.json, it should contains {username: "name", password: "admin"}, like this.

Comment: before that, have you solved `FileNotFoundException` error ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't solve the path problem, I use the local absolute path (which is ok). But I can't use the file with the path "data/user.json".

Comment: there are two buttons in index.html. One will go to login and another will go to register. I don't see how they link to `FileTool`

Comment: I once thought about that but with no access, I will try to deal with it, thank you very much.

Comment: In order you need this https://crunchify.com/how-to-write-json-object-to-file-in-java/

Comment: Thanks, so kind of you.