# Adding an ImageIcon to a JLabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

My program will run, and a button will appear, but the image which is in the res folder that is in a referenced library will not appear (`egg.png`). There are no errors, but I'm confused as to why it won't run properly.

```
package gui;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class IconButton {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DefaultButton");

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Jack Young\\Desktop\\Egg game Sprites");
    JButton button = new JButton();
    button.setIcon(image);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: You mention `"egg.png"` but use `"C:\\Users\\Jack Young\\Desktop\\Egg game Sprites"` ... so I am not suprised, provided the correct file name and this will work.

Comment: You also mention "res" folder, but that path doesn't mention any "res" folders

Comment: in the code i posted i had the path from my computer posted, but it didn't work so i tried to change it just the egg.png that i had in my res folder.

Comment: But just `new ImageIcon("egg.png");` won't cut it either since it will look at the root of the project. See [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Comment: i was able to make it work by using "C:\\Users\\Jack Young\\Desktop\\Eclipse\\GUI\\res\\egg.png"  is there a way to simplify it to something to the effect of "egg.png"

Comment: @Jack Young Yes, if you add the image to the root of your project path you can just call it by its filename.

Comment: Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL.

Answer (score 0):

try this:- for eg:-
if image is in icons folder in resource:-

private final ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("icons/image.png"));