# Reading file on my spring static resources always null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inputstream

Can someone explain me how do i read my jrxml as inputstream under my static resources.

This is my resigtered resource path

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("WEB-INF/resources/");
```

under resources i have reports folder, under reports folder i have samplereport.jrxml

i use these codes but it always throws filenotfound exception

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/reports/samplereport.jrxml");
    InputStream resourceInputStream = resource.getInputStream();
```

I tried this and moved my samplereport.jrxml at the same path of my class and it work.

```
InputStream employeeReportStream
      = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/samplereport.jrxml");
```

But i dont want to work on this way. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Remove slash before reports like below code.

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("reports/samplereport.jrxml");
```

Refer below URL for more info regarding loading files.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

[How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Comment: This is not working, java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [reports/samplereport.jrxml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ResourceUtils` class for reading  resource locations to files in the file system.

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:reports/file1.txt")

 //File is found
System.out.println("File Found : " + file.exists());

//Read File Content

String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));

System.out.println(content);
```

But, if you are using Spring then only `ResourceUtils` class is helps.(`java.lang.Object.org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils`)

Answer (score 0):

You may made mistake in this path:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/resources/");
```

instead of

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("WEB-INF/resources/");
```