# Tomcat Web Application Resource File placement

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, intellij-idea, web-applications

I have a little Java Web Application project using IntelliJ, Tomcat and jersey.

My project structure looks like this:

```
src
    main
        java
            package
                   Main.java
        resources
    test
web
    WEB-INF
          web.xml
    index.jsp
```

I want to add a resource xml file. It should be deployed with some initial values and it should be possible to read from the file and also to write to it - all from java code. It should not be accessible directly from, let's say, a browser.

Where should I put that file and how can I access it when I've put it there?

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46452118/3888766

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem.