# Can't resolve method readAllBytes()

Tags: java, gradle, client-server

### What I’m trying to do

I'm trying to build a java.net application where client and server have to send data to each other via serialised collection types as `byte[]`.

### The problem

For an unknown reason my DataInputStream can't resolve the method `readAllBytes()`.

A friend threw it in his IDE and it didn't complain. I'm unsure how this could be a version issue, but I checked and I didn't misconfigure my project. I'm using Java 8.

```java
  public void startClient() {
        try {
            Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 7000);
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            out.writeUTF("Hi i'm " + client.getLocalSocketAddress());
            DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            byte[] sent = input.readAllBytes(); //"can't resolve method 'readAllBytes()'
            getDataFromClient(input.readAllByes());//"can't resolve method 'readAllBytes()'
            client.close();


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[image]

I'm actually sure this method should be supported, but I can't figure out why it isn't [since it is listed as a method, inherited from Input Stream (docs.oracle.com)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html).

The project, containing the method is also a Gradle Project. Hence, to complete the picture, this is the *build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = ["src/main/java"]
            includes = ["**/*.fxml","**/*.png"]
        }
    }
}

group 'prog3'
version '0.1'
mainClassName='Client'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.1.0'
}
```

**Edit:** Turns out as per the answers, Java 8 was insufficient and I should have used Java 9. Classic RTFM question.

Comment: You're compiling for java 8 but the docs are for java 9.

Comment: `readAllBytes()` is only available starting in Java 9.

Comment: I had the same issue, when I was working with intellij IDEA IDE. I thought I was compiling for java 11, but instead I was compiling for java 8. If you are working with intellij IDEA IDE, you can check compiler.xml file inside .idea folder and check the `<bytecodeTargetLevel target="11" />` element.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per [`InputStream.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) method javadoc this method was introduced in Java 9.

> Since:
>
> 9

It won't work when the code is compiled on lower Java version, in your case Java 8.

Comment: The solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java