# How to determine correct path to open a file with PrintWriter?

Tags: java, file, printwriter

When creating a `PrinterWriter` object:

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(*FileName*);
```

Where is the compiler looking when it goes to find *FileName*? For example, in Eclipse I am working in *Arrays/src/ArraysAndFiles.java*. In this example I am trying to open *Values.txt*. I have created this file in the *src* directory since that is where *ArraysAndFiles.java* is stored. When I attempt to open the file in the following code  I get a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class ArraysAndFiles {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Values.txt");

    }
}
```

What is the proper path to *Values.txt*?

Comment: When you pass a path to `PrintWritier` it is looking in the file system of the OS, you can right-click your file to see its full path and pass that to the `PrintWriter`. **However**, when you JAR your code you wont exactly be able to write to files inside that running JAR. This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), what is your actual goal so someone can help you achieve it?

Comment: The other way to open a file is to use a `JFileChooser` and let the user pick out the file for you.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html

Comment: Place the file into the project directory `/Arrays`.

Comment: @xtratic I am reading *Starting Out with Java* and was only trying to follow along with a "Working with Arrays and Files" example.

Comment: I'm not sure what that example entails, what is your goal?  *If you don't care about your code working when it is Jarred, and this is just an experiment,* then simply correct the path to be the full path according to the OS file system, eg. `C:\...\...\...\Arrays\src\Values.txt`.

Comment: @Thank you this worked. But the task was open a file with `Print Writer` and then write the contents of an array to it using using a loop and .`println()`

Answer (score 0):

**Solution #1** (recommended for small files but you have the benefit that file will be found in other computers as well): [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

**Solution #2:** Build the path step by step by using `File(String parent, String child)` constructor. Example:

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Desktop");
File textsFolder = new File(desktop,"texts");
File testsFolder = new File(textsFolder,"tests");
File peopleTxt = new File(testsFolder,"people,txt");
```

Which is equals to: C://Users//George//Desktop//texts//tests//people.txt (Windows OS).

Answer (score -1):

In your example "Values.txt" is a relative path. It's relative to your **working directory**. 
Usually it's the same directory where your JAR file resides.

In Eclipse an application is built in the 'bin' folder. In your case it's `Arrays\bin\`. So this is the working directory for the application and your file has to be there.

If you want Eclipse to export this file during the Build process, do the following:

> Right click on the file -> Build Path -> Add to Build Path

Answer (score -1):

As per code,

`PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("Values.txt");`

if you place your `Values.txt` in current/project directory i.e. in `Arrays` folder it should work but there are limitation as mentioned in above comments like writing to the file which is a part of JarFile.

Depending upon your purpose, you should take the action.