# How to get the path to a file in src/main/resources folder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, resources

Assume standard maven setup.
I have a file abc.conf in src/main/resources folder of my project.
How do i get the absolute path to abc.conf in the code?

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder

Answer (score 1):

You'll be able to elicit the [path of the resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder) in the JAR, but the running program can't know, where your development repository is, unless you supply the information explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

When you run your app, you are not using the resource file in your code folder(src/main/resources) but the ones in the target folder([yourProject]\target as default) where you build to.The target folder path can be changed, it's not a absolute path.

So you can use a "absolute" path out of the content you run or use a "relative" path to the target folder.

Answer (score 0):

Maven automatically sets the current working directory, then you can just use:

```
File resourcesDirectory = new File("src/main/resources/abc.conf");
    
System.out.println( resourcesDirectory.getAbsolutePath() ); //prints absolute path of your abc.conf
```

I hope it helps.