# Unable to read property file from a spring boot jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read a property file from a spring boot project

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:myspecialconfig.properties"));
```

This file is present in main/resources. So in effect reaches BOOT-INF\classes

But I get the error

class path resource [myspecialconfig.properties] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:myjar.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/myspecialconfig.properties

Comment: I don't think you need classpath: at all to load it, but as answer suggested there are better ways of doing it

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder