# java - how to provide path of file from jar to other function

Tags: java

I am creating an application (hive udf) and for that I am creating an fat jar with all the dependencies. As this is going to be distributed over multiple nodes I need to pack my property files in jar as well.

**Problem** 
 One of the function I am calling from another jar needs a parameter, a property file path. I have packed this property file inside jar. and passing just the name. However, it's complaining that file not found.

**Code:**

```
  c = new ABC("classification.props");
```

Function inside **ABC** class that read the property file

```java
public static Properties getProperties(String propFile) {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile));
        return props;
    } catch (IOException var3) {
        var3.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

This ABC is coming from another jar. however I am creating a fat jar so shouldn't matter. **classification.props** is in the root folder of application.

Comment: Is the complaining code trying to load the properties file from the filesystem, or from the class path?

Comment: @dnault  I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

The `getProperties` method is looking for a file on the filesystem. That's not where your file is -- your file is in the JAR.

If you can change the getProperties` method, you can tell it to read the file as a class path resource instead.

[How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

If you can't modify the `getProperties` method, you can copy the properties to the filesystem (load it as a class path resource using the technique in the linked answer, and then write to to a temp directory).