# Deploy a jar file with resource files in heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a .jar file in Heroku using the maven plugin. I have two files in `src/main/resources` folder read using the `File` class in the program. I'm able to access them when executing the jar file normally but when deployed to Heroku, I can't figure where they are stored. Running `jar tf <filename>.jar` gives the two files to not be in a folder. What's the path to the two files when deployed to Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Class#getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [Class#getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)). It will give you access to files in your packaged JAR file as either an URL or InputStream.

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data.json");
```

A similar question has been [asked and answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder).

Answer (score 0):

i use this code in my project when it need add some files in target directory

```
<build>
    <resource>
    <directory>./src/main/resources</directory> 
        <targetPath>./</targetPath>
    </resource> 
    <resource> 
    <!-- mkdir -->
    <directory>./filestorage</directory>
    <targetPath>../filestorage</targetPath>
    </resource>
<build>
```