# Eclipse not using relative file path

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, filepath

I have some problem in my eclipse settings. I am trying to open/use a XSD file in my class but it doesn't seem to find it as the code isn't using relative path. When I copy the absolute path from my computer and paste it, it seems to work. But I need to use relative path as this project will be exported and may be used by others.

This is what Im trying to do:
`Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("myfilename.xsd"));`

This is what I get in the console:
`Failed to read schema document 'file:/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/sisrep.xsd, because 1) could not find the document;`

When I do `Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("Users/username/etc/etcabsoultepath/myfilename.xsd"));` it works fine, so im guessing eclipse isn't using the relative path.

Also, this code is run on a servlet. I had imported a sample java application file and run a similar operation, and that file was getting the relative path as needed, but my project isnt able to. Is there any setting I need to change or specify in eclipse for my project? I tried add `.\\` before the file name but it didnt seem to work.

Comment: A *relative path* is relative to the *working directory* of the process, i.e. of the running Java program. Why do you believe that the *working directory* is `Users/username/etc/etcabsoultepath` when running from Eclipse? --- *"this code is run on a servlet"* What do you believe the *working directory* of the Servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) is, and why do you believe that? Servlet code should **never** rely on the *working directory*.

Comment: Add the file as a resource and read it from the classpath. It will be much easier to work in different environments this way. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15749192/2587435)

Comment: Servlets shouldn't access *on-disk* resources outside of the web application. Put the schema in your application.