# NullPointerException when trying to read a file from resources folder

Tags: java, gradle, properties

I would like to read a property file, like this:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(MajorBot.class.getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
```

But when I am trying to do this I get an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: inStream parameter is null
> at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:246)
> at java.base/java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:406)
> at majorbot.MajorBot.main(MajorBot.java:13)

My app was created using IntelliJ, new Gradle/Java project. After creation, there was a `resources` directory allready there. I have created `application.properties` there, but I cannod read this file.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: You can try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15749281/14152955) this should work but I didn't tested

Answer (score 0):

`getResourceAsStream` will try to find your file in a subfolder of `resources` that matches your current class’s package. If you want to access a file that is not in a subfolder, specify it as e.g. `“/application.properties”`.

Comment: Your suggestion is correct, but it doesn’t use the “current class”—it uses the package of the class whose `getResource` method is being called.