# Folder path / distance

Tags: java

I have a problem setting the file path in a Java FX application. I set the folder path to the "src" folder ( 'File file = new File ("src / hostbaze.txt");' ) and when i run it via netbeans it loads without any problems, everything works ok. The problem is when I run the application via the Java icon, via the Java application located in "C: \ Users \ almir \ Documents \ NetBeansProjects \ EEIPTV \ **dist**" ... then it can't load that file because the file is not in "**dist**" than in "**src**", and in "**dist**" this file cannot be saved.

Comment: Consider [reading the data as a resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder) rather than a file (if file is read-only).  If you must read and write files, then consider [using either paths relative to the current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871051/how-to-get-the-current-working-directory-in-java) or paths specifically configured or chosen by a user.

Comment: I replaced the javafx tag with a java tag as this is a general Java question, not a JavaFX-specific question.

Comment: No `src` dir at runtime.

Comment: Hi there, please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

If the file is updated externally, you can read a text file and give it a relative path like so:

```
new File("../src/hostbaze.txt");
```

However, be aware that this is a sketchy way of doing things because the file may not exist on other developers systems.

If the resource is needed for runtime, you can put it into the `src/resources` folder and have it compiled with the source on compile-time, then read it with:

```
getClass().getResource("hostbaze.txt");
```