# How do I create resources folder in Intellij correctly?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, resources, filepath

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to call a file named "sample-lite.json" to my main Driver class.

I created a folder named "data" within the "resources" folder that was automatically created when I first started the project with Maven and put the JSON files into the "data" folder.

However, I get FileNotFoundException even though Intellij's auto-filling correctly provided the right path to my JSON file.

Strangely, when I moved my JSON files directly under "src" folder, everything works as intended.

I also checked the Project Structure of my project but the "resources" folder is correctly indicated in the content root.

How can I safely call my JSON files while keeping them under the "resources" folder?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder

Comment: You need to use GetResourceAsStream() method to get the resource