# Gradle does not include resource folder to jar

Tags: java, gradle

I am having a little trouble building jar from gradle project. Namely gradle doesn't include my resource folder even though i have it specified in build.gradle as shown below:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

application {
    mainClass = 'skorupinski.xmass.Main'
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['./src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['./src/main/resources']
        }
    }
}

jar {  
    manifest {  
        attributes(  
                'Main-Class': 'skorupinski.xmass.Main'  
        )  
    }  

    baseName = 'hi'
}
```

There are images in the resource folder that I load into my java program. When I run the jar file it returns an error that it coudln't file the image file unless i put the jar in the same directory as src folder.

[My file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M8Kq.png)

Comment: How do you load the image file? I'm quite sure that Gradle does what it always does and includes the resource folder. Maybe your way of trying to load the image is the real problem.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I load it by the path "src/main/resources/image.png", when I run it without building into a jar it works perfectly.

Comment: To get resources placed in my jar file I specify this in my jar task: `from (buildDir) { include 'pattern' }`.

Comment: @JeffHolt I tried it this way: ```from('src/main') { include 'resources/*.png' }``` without effect

Comment: What does '.' mean in file/path/directory context?? Correct! Current directory!;)

Comment: To load a packaged resource you must not use the full path ("src/main/resources/image.png") packaging it into the jar drops the first part of the path ("src/main/resource"), within the jar the path is only "image.png"

Comment: @xerx593 after removing '.' before /src/main/resources I can tell you that it wasn't the case

Comment: @ThomasKläger I tried to load it by './image.png' and it still doesnt work.

Comment: Do you really load the resource (as noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15749260: `InputStream is = MyTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/image.png");`) or are you trying to load it from the filesystem (`InputStream is = new FileInputStream("./image.png");`)? Because packaged resource do not exist in the filesystem, you cannot access them with `java.io.File` / `java.io.FileInputStream` and similar

Comment: @ThomasKläger I use this code and as arguments I give "./", "image.png" ```InputStream inputStream = ImageLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(path + filename);``` It returns null

Comment: `/` means root (*when* you are lucky..in windows, it will point to `C:\`)..

Comment: If the image file is in the resources folder directly then the path must be "/" - using "./" will search it in the same directory as the `ImageLoader` class (i.e. if the `ImageLoader` class is in the com.example package using "./image.png" will search the image in the "com/example" resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try exclusively specifying the `include` in jar section of build.gradle

```
jar { 

// try adding this
    from('src/main/resources') {
       include '**/*.*'
    }

 
    manifest {  
        attributes(  
                'Main-Class': 'skorupinski.xmass.Main'  
        )  
    }  

    baseName = 'hi'
}
```

Comment: It now includes the directory, but returns an error that every single png in there is a duplicate and there is no duplicate strategy set.

Comment: So the files are already there in the jar. Then the problem could be with your code as to how your are accessing it through the code or may be something wrong with manifest file. Could you pls unpack your jar and check it's manifest file? I am particularly interested to see the `Class-Path` definition