# Where to put resources and access it in Java Project (in IntelliJ)? How to read from it then?

Tags: java, file, path, classpath, filereader

I have text file, which I want to read from, but I don`t really know how to navigate from the class path to the path where the file is.

This is my project structure:
[Project structure photo(Intellij)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mSZS.png)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        URL fileURL = Main.class.getResource("resources/coding_qual_input.txt");
        if (fileURL != null) {
            File file = new File(fileURL.getFile());
            try {
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know, if put the file correctly, but right now the `new FileReader(file)` gets me `null`.

So, why can't the `FileReader` read my file?

As `Main.class.getResource("resources/coding_qual_input.txt")` results in `file:/C:/Users/Jonas/IdeaProjects/Android%20ATC/pyramidDecoder/out/production/pyramidDecoder/resources/coding_qual_input.txt`, I don't see where the problem is.

Should I navigate somehow down the classpath?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I load a file from resource folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15749192/how-do-i-load-a-file-from-resource-folder)

Comment: all seems correct, i tried to replicate your code and structure on my machine and it's work (it's a meme, Mario). try to use ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream instead of Main.class.getResource, maybe the 'Android%20ATC' folder is something that annoyng JVM (dunno)

Comment: Does not really help, but thanks. When I try `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("/resources/coding_qual_input.txt")`, I get `null` and I don't want it as `InputStream`, but in a `FileReader`

Comment: why you need specifically a FileReader ? it's just a Reader that read files, you can read a generic InputStream via InputStreamReader that is still a Reader

Comment: The problem was the "space" in "Android ATC" directory. Thank you, @StefanoRiffaldi

Comment: @JonasOhlendorf yrwlk, would u pls check the answer below ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, as I suspected, the space (%20) in the folder name seems to not be nice with URL, so I've recreated that behavior and got a `FileNotFoundException` (using Java 1.8)

Using `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream` all works fine, here's:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("resources/coding_qual_input.txt");
    if (inputStream != null) {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }
}
```

or (but I really discourage it) use `String.replace` to substitute "%20" with " " and still use `URL`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL fileURL = Main.class.getResource("resources/coding_qual_input.txt");
    System.out.println(fileURL);
    if (fileURL != null) {
        File file = new File(fileURL.getFile().replace("%20", " "));
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

or (again, not the best way imho) use `URL.openStream` to directly open an `InputStream` without use `File`

```
InputStream inputStream = fileURL.openStream();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
for (String line = in.readLine(); line != null; line = in.readLine()) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```